# Linear Regression through origin

Tags: data-science

While performing Linear Regression (through origin) in R, the way R-square is calculated is by taking (y_hat-0) instead of (y_hat-y_bar)? What is the reason of doing this as in this exercise, we are trying to compare our model against a reference model which should remain the same as Y_bar?

Answer (score 1):

When we do regression through origin 
the assumption we are making is

> y_bar is 0.

Hence, we should use

> y_hat-0

instead of

> y_hat-y_bar